# restore postgres db from folder after hardware crash

Tags: postgresql, database-restore, ubuntu-18.04, pg-restore

I have a postgres 10 DB running on Ubunto 18.04.
The dump backup is too old to use.
After a hardware crash I managed to save all the directories and files from the old disk, but the disk cannot be used. 
Installed a new postgres 10 on other computer running 18.04.
Tried to copy the files to the new postgres environment - recieved tons of fatal error messages. 
What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: You need to describe everything you did *exactly*, including the error messages. You should either hire a PostgreSQL expert or live with the data loss.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer. I found the solution and I am more then happy to share it:

In case you have a [directory backup] of your database and want to restore it. 
The better way will be to use Postgres Backup and restore. This answer is only for people that do not have a good PG backup, or an updated one...

See that you have a Postgres installation on your machine. If the database is used by other users - make sure you do all the restoration on a test non active PG server.

Postgres data directory usually looks like that (Ubuntu 18.04 Postgres 10):
[Postgres 10 data directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKJAj.png)

switch user to postgres (not necessary but makes it a lot easier):

```
su postgres
```

make sure Postgres is stopped.

```
pg_ctl stop
```

move the current directory for backup. $PGDATA should point to the data dir. 
in my installation it's "/var/lib/postgresql/10/main/". Be sure the [target_dir] exists

```
cd $PGDATA
mv -r . [target_dir]
```

copy the backup directory to $PGDATA

```
cp -r [directory backup] $PGDATA
```

change the permissions (postgres doesn't love permissions to other...)

```
chmod -R 0700 $PGDATA
```

check to see if no file or dir is missing...

start postgres

```
pg_ctl start
```

Good luck!